# Difference between Pure EdDSA (ed25519) and HashEdDSA (ed25519ph)

Tags: elliptic-curves, signature, ed25519

My question refers to EdDSA as specified in [RFC 8032](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8032).

I get from the RFC that **ed25519** and **ed25519ph** are two different instances of EdDSA mainly differing in the fact that that in the case of **ed25519ph** the hash of the message is signed.

Step 2 of the Sign process is:

$SHA\mbox{-}512(dom2(F, C) || prefix || PH(M))$

where in the case of **ed25519** the $PH$ function is the identity function and in the case of **ed25519ph** its for example an implementation of **SHA512**. However, the part I am curious about it that this isn't the only difference between the two.

According to the RFC $dom2(F,C)$ actually is also different:

> dom2(x, y):
> The blank octet string when signing or verifying
> Ed25519.  Otherwise, the octet string: "SigEd25519 no
> Ed25519 collisions" || octet(x) || octet(OLEN(y)) ||
> y, where x is in range 0-255 and y is an octet string
> of at most 255 octets.  "SigEd25519 no Ed25519
> collisions" is in ASCII (32 octets).

What's the reason for that?
If this wasn't the case one could construct **ed25519ph** by simply hashing the message and passing it as input to an implementation of **ed25519**. The way its specified this construction wouldn't be compatible to an implementation of **ed25519ph** (because of the **dom2** prefix).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just a preventive measure. Without this separation, an attacker knowing `ed25519ph(m)` would also learn `ed25519(h(m))`.

I'm not aware of any real-world protocol using both simultaneously and where that would be an issue, but it's not far-fetched to think that it could be the case.

Domain separation is good hygiene and has become very common in new designs.

The choice of `dom2()` being a blank string when using `ed25519` was only made to remain compatible with existing implementations.